# How do I make my bot ignore people with the ignored role?

Tags: discord.js

Regarding the question, here is an example:
I made an auto-moderator bot that warns and deletes a mention of the owner of the server and whenever a staff member mentions the owner for urgent reasons or whatever, the bot still warns and deletes the mention of the user and adds a warn to the staff member for no reason as they just needed the owner's attention. Is there a solution to this problem?

I don't have any code sorry :(( but please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if the member has the role by either using `MemberRoleManager#has()` or `MemberRoleManager#some()`

[An example by the Discord.JS Guide](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/permissions.html#roles-as-bot-permissions)